# Stored procedure rounds returned fields, but calling from PHP function shows unrounded fields

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2012, and PHP 7.4. I have a stored procedure called `temp` that returns a number rounded to 2 decimal places.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE temp AS
SELECT
    ROUND(t.Real_Weight_Per_Part, 2) as realWeightPerPart
FROM t

EXEC temp
```

The result:

[image]

Which is what I expect. However, when I call this stored procedure from PHP like so:

```
$sql = "EXEC temp";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$data = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I get the following response in `$data`:

```
[
    {"realWeightPerPart": "11.359999999999999"},
    {"realWeightPerPart": "60.5"},
    {"realWeightPerPart": "11.359999999999999"},
    ...
]
```

Why is it that when I am in the SQL Server window and I execute the stored procedure, I get the rounded results, but when I execute it from PHP I get the unrounded results?

Comment: What datatype is `Real_Weight_Per_Part`?

Comment: My bet is the driver converting to float and that's why you get this result. You may need to iterate each value and round again in PHP, or use PDO::FETCH_FUNC with round function as parameter .

Comment: Seems to be [a quirk in how floats are represented](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75920). Try `CAST(ROUND(t.Real_Weight_Per_Part, 2) AS VARCHAR(255))`. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23120584/why-does-mysql-round-floats-way-more-than-expected. It's written about MySQL but probably applies to SQL Server as well.

Comment: Instead of casting to varchar, cast to decimal, floats cannot represent some numbers accurately. But a decimal can (I suspect you should be using decimal in the first place).

Comment: Casting to decimal worked for me. Thanks for all your help!